# How to run a script on a remote machine using the screen command and ssh?

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

I'd like to run on a list of servers and run remotely a script while using `screen`.

Manually, I'd do:

```
screen -RD
./run_script
```

and manually remotely I'd do:

```
ssh root@server "screen -RD && ./run_script"
```

but what happens in reality is that `screen -RD` is running and when I type `exit` only then it starts running the script.

So how can it be achieved to run `screen -RD` remotely and then issue a command within the first screen terminal?

Edit #1:

```
[root@edge14 ~]# screen -r -X /nfs/ops/component/edge/scripts/move_stuck_aggfiles_to_hadoop.sh && screen -RD
No screen session found.
[root@edge14 ~]#
```

Comment: I don't know why this question was voted down without any explanation but it certainly placed in the right site as this is a question regarding servers in production environment.

Comment: This isn't a sysadmin question, though - you're using end-user applications on your server. Which is perfectly OK in itself, but the question fits better on Unix/Linux, and I've voted to move it there.

Comment: (Also, ssh:ing in as root pretty much warrants a downvote in and of itself...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use the `-X` switch. From the man page:

> ```
>   -X   Send  the specified command to a running screen session. You can
>         use the -d or -r option to tell screen to look only for attached
>         or detached screen sessions. Note that this command doesn't work
>         if the session is password protected.
> ```

To combine this with actually seeing the screen:

```
ssh root@server "screen -dr -X ./run_script && screen -RD"
```

(But you **really** should not allow ssh logins as root, it's very bad practice from a security standpoint.)

Comment: Thanks, once I run it using the `-X` switch, how can I display the running process or how can I view it's stdout?

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: I missed the `-d`.